# A null reference could result in runtime

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim policy_key() As RenewalClaim.PolicyKeyType
policy_key(0).policyEffectiveDt = date_format_string(ld_EffectiveDate)
```

Getting error at Line2.

> An Error occured - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element of object arrays also needs to be declared as a new object too.

```
Dim policy_key() As RenewalClaim.PolicyKeyType
Redim policy_key(0)
policy_Key(0) = new RenewalClaim.PolicyKeyType
policy_key(0).policyEffectiveDt = date_format_string(ld_EffectiveDate)
```

QUICK TIP: When declaring classes structures etc, it is useful to name them so you can see what type they are....

e.g.
cls_Policy_Key for a class

str_Policy_Key for a structure etc.

When you come back to your code after a year.. you will thank yourself for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim policy_key() As RenewalClaim.PolicyKeyType
```

is part of your problem. When you are declaring policy_key() you are actually declaring it as an array with no elements. If you don't particularly need to use an array, for example, if you don't need to add objects to a particular element number, you might be better using a list and declaring it like this

```
Dim policy_key As New List(Of RenewalClaim.PolicyKeyType)
```

This way, you can add items easily without having to resize your array each time -  The code is a little longer than Trevor's answer, but less prone to errors when you extend your code -

```
dim newPolicy_Key as RenewalClaim.PolicyKeyType
newPolicy_Key.policyEffectiveDt = date_format_string(ld_EffectiveDate)
policy_Key.add(newPolicyKey)
```

Comment: Array is one of webservice's request parameter, and I have to pass it as it is with filling elements. So can you please suggest me a way out using it as an array only.